# ALSB automation

Tags: weblogic, wlst, alsb

One of the elegant things about WebLogic is WLST (Weblogic Scripting).  Is it possible to script actions done in ALSB (Aqualogic Service Bus)?

For example:  Exporting resources from the bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out how to export.  You need to grab an instance of ALSBConfigurationMBean like so.

```
 if currentTree() != domainRuntime:
    domainRuntime()

alsbConfigBean = findService(ALSBConfigurationMBean.NAME, ALSBConfigurationMBean.TYPE)
```

From there you just do a query for the correct references.  Documentation for ALSBConfigurationMBean is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11036_01/alsb30/javadoc/com/bea/wli/sb/management/configuration/ALSBConfigurationMBean.html)

Found some sample Jython code [here](http://code.google.com/p/guavatools/source/browse/trunk/JardenPOC/ALSBSync/conf/export.py?spec=svn57&r=57)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes. Check out [Using deployment APIs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13171_01/alsb/docs30/deploy/config_appx.html).